# hostname shows as vps Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, server, hostname, vps

Hi i am using  a ubuntu server , **some other person has made it** . i checked my host name by typing `hostname`  it says `vps` .

I checked in my `etc/hostname` file it says the name is `vps`

in `/ect/hosts` file it has

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       vps.xxxxxx.no vps
xxx.xx.xxx.xx   xxxxxx.com
```

and `xxx.xx.xxx.xx` is my site's ip address

also this site is accessed by a url different than `xxxxxx.com` . lets say my sitec is accessed via `zzzzzzz.com`

**my problems are**

in `/ect/hosts` it says site host is `xxxxxx.com` but you can access it by a different name `zzzzzzz.com` . so where can you set that setting ?

also my hostname is showing as `vps` and what is the logic behind that

I Know these are dumb questions but I can not find any thing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be ware that the names and their corresponding IP addresses defined inside your server (by `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`) are only known by your server.
You can define anything you like there.

Outside your server, there are the DNS servers that will offer a name to IP address resolution to the Internet users. The name defined into the DNS may be different from the one defined into the server.

Also, on the machine from which you are accessing your server, there may be some `/etc/hosts` file with another name used to map to the IP address of your server.

So, your server with IP **a.b.c.d** can be called **vps** internally (`/etc/hostname` & `/etc/hosts`).
On the Internet, there may be offical DNS name **XXXXXX.com** pointing to **a.b.c.d**.
On local desktop, you can even have a local `/etc/hosts` file where you have the name **ZZZZZZ.com** defined for **a.b.c.d**.

Comment: yes i can understand , thnk you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

> In /ect/hosts it says site host is xxxxxx.com but you can access it by a different name zzzzzzz.com . So where can you set that setting ?

I would start checking

- the router.
- for a DNS server. Since it is called vps it might be a virtual system.

> Also my hostname is showing as vps and what is the logic behind that

It is just a name in hosts as far as we can tell. You should ask the creator of the server but generally speaking: VPS means virtual private server. If that is what it is you might consider the name appropriate.